# Eliminar elemento int de un ArrayList por la referencia del número y no el índice usando "remove"

Tags: java, arraylist, eliminar, colecciones, agregación

Buenas tengo una duda de como eliminar un elemento de un *ArrayList* tengo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numeroA = new Arraylist();
int x = 20;
numeroA.add(x);
numeroA.remove(0)
```

Lo que hago en este caso es agregar un elemento y después borro el elemento que este en la primera posición. La cosa es que según el teórico que tengo puedo eliminar un elemento haciendo referencia al elemento en si.
Ej:

```
int x = 30;
numeroA.add(x);
numeroA.remove(30)
```

Y esto debería eliminar el numero 30. La duda es al hacer el *remove* como yo indico que estoy haciendo referencia al índice o al elemento, lo probé en java con Arraylist y solo lo toma como índice, si uso conjuntos si me elimina el 30, pero según lo que tengo debería funcionar para conjuntos y lista. Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno según la documentación, cuando le envías un valor **int** siempre asumirá que es un índice, por esa razón tenemos que enviarle un objeto y no un int. ;)

---

[Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-):

> **remove(int index)**
> Elimina el elemento en la posición especificada en esta lista.
>
> **remove(Object o)**
> Elimina la primera aparición del elemento especificado de esta lista, si está presente.

---

Vamos a explicarlo con un ejemplo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList();
numeros.add(20);
numeros.add(30);
numeros.add(40);
numeros.add(50);
System.out.println(numeros.toString());
```

> [20, 30, 40, 50]

Como ves en la documentación puedes enviar como referencia *el objeto que quieres eliminar* entonces solo bastaría con hacer:

```
numeroA.remove(new Integer(20));
```

Donde con `new Integer(20)` estarías creando el objeto entero como tal y haciendo referencia al mismo, quedando así:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numeros= new ArrayList();
numeros.add(20);
numeros.add(30);
numeros.add(40);
numeros.add(50);
numeros.remove(new Integer(20));
System.out.println(numeros.toString());
```

> [30, 40, 50]

Comment: Perfecto , muchísimas gracias ahora que me decís me doy cuenta int es del tipo primitivo y al recibir un objeto tiene que ser integer